# Can't get mongoose to properly save an array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to build an e-commerce from scratch using NodeJS, express and mongoose following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL55RiY5tL51rajp7Xr_zk-fCFtzdlGKUp but when I `save()` the program ends up writing a duplicate of everything and keeping the original too.

I've tried using `updateMany()` and `insertMany()` but it didn't help.

This is the Schema located in product.js

```
const schema = new Schema({
  imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  description: {type: String, required: true},
  price: {type: Number, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

And this is in product-seeder.js

```
const Product = require('../models/product');

const products = [
  new Product({
    imagePath: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41mPFjDCaXL.jpg',
    title: 'Gfuel 1',
    description: 'Lorem Ipsum',
    price: 20
  }), ...x4
]

let done = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
  products[i].updateOne((err, result) => {
    done++;
    if (done === products.length) {
      exit();
    }
  });
}

const exit = () => {
  mongoose.disconnect();
}
```

This works fine if there's nothing in the database but when I run this code multiple times, it keeps writing the same thing multiple times when it should just keep one of every object and if I change some info it should update it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `save` instead of `updateOne` there could nothing be updated because you didn't  pass a valid ObjectId and therefore there is no reference to what should be updated.

[Read the docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating) to see what I mean.

Let's assume your Product-seeder.js is to store the products into the database. If you want to modify them you have to get the single product or a set of products from the database, modify them and save them again.

```
const Product = require('../models/product');

Product.find().exec((err, docs) => {
  if (err) return false; // log the error, send it to front-end, etc...
  docs.forEach((doc) => {
    doc.title = 'New Title here'
    doc.save()
  })
})
```

This should update every single product in your database. Now all your products should have the title "New Title here".

To get a single document use `findOne` with the `_id` attribute or `title` or anything else.

Comment: That works, but if I manually change the document, it doesn't update. I'd have to delete the collection and create it again.

Comment: Thats because you do not load the old documents from the database. You always create new ones. To update the old ones you have to load them with `Product.find()` like explained [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Comment: Thanks!! But exactly where should that `Product.find()` be? Could you point what should I change?

Comment: Updated my example! If you use something like `expressjs` you should define a new POST route with an id parameter to define which product will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the documents to be repeatedly created at every run, you need to make some key in your document as 'unique'.
Try setting the 'imagePath' in your schema as unique like below.

```
const schema = new Schema({ 
imagePath: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
title: {type: String, required: true},
description: {type: String, required: true},
price: {type: Number, required: true}});
```

Comment: That fixes the document repetition, thanks!!! Now I have to figure out a way to update everything automatically

Comment: If this has resolved your issue, would you mind accepting and upvoting the answer?